# How do I directly increment a cell value by 1 as part of a, LibraCalc, macro function

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am making a spreadsheet to tally votes for a car show.  I used basic years ago but it is not the same as writing a macro so I have been Using the macro record function in **LibraCalc** *(this is included with LibraOffice, an open source program similar to MS Office and Excel.)* I am able to select the cell I want to change from a table.  I copy the cell value to another cell, add 1 to the value, then save it back to the table as a value.

I would like a faster more direct method to directly increment the cell value while keeping the result as a value; without all the copy, move, and past steps.

My macro record function works but it is slower than what I want and not very elegant.  There can be several hundred votes to count so saving time is important.  My concern is an inefficient program will be too slow.

Comment: The macro recorder is not a good way to learn LO Basic. Instead start with https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php, which has a chapter on Calc, for example listing 6.3. Set cell value, format, string, or formula.

Comment: Please see the example from [**this post**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=106029#p515464). Perhaps this will be a little more efficient and better suited for your task.